# Discord API Inquiries

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently building a discord auto-joiner program, but Im unclear of which api to use right now. Below is my code

```
import requests

link = input('Discord Invite Link: ')
if len(link) > 6:
    link = link[19:]
apilink = "https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invite/" + str(link)

print(link)

with open('tokens.txt','r') as handle:
    tokens = handle.readlines()
    for x in tokens:
        token = x.rstrip()
        headers = {
            'Authorization': token
        }
        requests.post(apilink, headers=headers)
    print("All valid tokens have joined!")
```

I want to know will the api v6 too old to trigger a ban on my discord account? If yes, which api link should I use? Thanks.

Comment: "*I want to know will the api v6 too old to trigger a ban on my discord account*" Why would using an old version of an API trigger a ban on your discord account? Can you provide a source for this implicit claim?? "*If yes, which api link should I use?*" The one that meets your requirements, perhaps? v6 is deprecated and can be turned off or changed at any time, which means you probably shouldn't build anything new on it. Why do you continue to use it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be banned for automatically joining servers with user account tokens on *any version of the API*. [It goes against the TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-). If you'd like to join servers on behalf of other users, you should consider using [Discord's OAuth system](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2), specifically with the `guilds.join` permission.